# Maximal ideals of the quotient ring $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am asked to find all maximal ideals of the quotient ring $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3)$. Since every ideal of this quotient ring is of the form $I/(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3)$ where $I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ containing $(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3)$, this reduces to the problem finding all maximal ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ containing $(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3)$, but I can't see how to do this (maybe because $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is not a UFD). 
Any hints? (I've never seen any question like this before)

Comment: Please have a look into Groebner bases.

Comment: can you find some (all) the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3)\cong \mathbb C[y]/((3-2y)^2-y^3).$ Furthermore, since $(3-2y)^2-y^3$ has three distinct roots over $\Bbb C$, we have $\mathbb C[y]/((3-2y)^2-y^3)\cong \Bbb C^3,$ which has maximal ideals $(\Bbb C,\Bbb C,0),(\Bbb C,0,\Bbb C),$ and $(0,\Bbb C,\Bbb C).$ Now, find the images of these in $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^2-y^3,x+2y-3).$